# Cocos2d-x android app won't run

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to setup cocos2d-x on mac.
I've downloaded all the staff and install it.
Now i want to run simple HelloWorld cocos2d-x app on eclipse, but unfortunately it won't run correctly, it gives me "Unfortunately app has stopped working" message.
After looking for  some info on logs, found the following [image]

I know that the library should create the build_native.py script, and before running the app,  firstly i execute this file, but no result.
Maybe someone has the issue before?

```
08-29 12:49:01.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1420): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 12:49:01.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1420): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load cocos2dcpp: findLibrary returned null
08-29 12:49:01.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
08-29 12:49:01.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
08-29 12:49:01.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onLoadNativeLibraries(Cocos2dxActivity.java:66)
08-29 12:49:01.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onCreate(Cocos2dxActivity.java:80)
08-29 12:49:01.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
08-29 12:49:01.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
08-29 12:49:01.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
08-29 12:49:01.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
08-29 12:49:01.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
08-29 12:49:01.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
08-29 12:49:01.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-29 12:49:01.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-29 12:49:01.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-29 12:49:01.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 12:49:01.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-29 12:49:01.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-29 12:49:01.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-29 12:49:01.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: copy & paste as text, images are hard to read

Comment: Make sure that the cocos2d libraries are added to the project build path and exported.

Comment: I'm completely new in Android development and Eclipse, could you please tell me how to check it ?

Answer (score 0):

You should link the source folder that contains the Java specific Source Files to your eclipse project.
These files should be located in PROJECT_PATH/cocos2d/cocos/platform/android/java/src.

In eclipse you just Right click your project> Build Path > Link Source > and follow the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use ./build_native.sh to compile? If you already did it you could run the next command in your Cygwin:

```
/<android-path>/sdk/platform-tools/adb logcat | ./ndk-stack -sym /<your-android-project/android/obj/local/armeabi
```

In the android ndk directory.

Answer (score 0):

You should have in *Eclipse* two projects the **HelloWorld** project and the other is a **cocos2dx library**

Here are two tutorials covering what you have to do to setup cocos2dx for android platform

[Reference 1](http://wizardfu.com/book/cocos2d-x/project-setup/)
[Reference 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5527/getting-started-with-android-development)

Your problem here that you have to add the **cocos2dx library** to *Eclipse* and add a reference for it in the **HelloWorld** project

Comment: library project is also exist, no result

Comment: You added this library project to the HelloWorld project ?